# Jenkins change credential in Credentials plugin

Tags: jenkins

A Jenkins install on my server was done by someone who no longer works for the company. Upon loading the management site (on the default port, 8080), I see a "log in" link, and the page that's linked to does not allow me to create an account. When I go to Credentials > Global Credentials, I see the name of that person.

So, basically my question is.... how can I take on the administrative role for Jenkins?

This is on windows. I can make the service run under my account. I am an admin on the machine and I have access to modify the credentials.xml file.

Comment: Jenkins *is* a programming tool, but this is a server-administration question nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If your Jenkins server is using an internal user database (or an external LDAP directory) and if you have a Jenkins/LDAP user account, edit the main Jenkins config.xml file and go this section:

```
<authorizationStrategy>
```

Add the following line:

```
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:YOUR_USERNAME</permission>
```

Restart the Jenkins service, you should be admin.

**Solution 2**

If you don't have a local/LDAP Jenkins account, you can disable the security and re-implement a new security strategy.

Please backup your Jenkins configuration (zip all the xml files) and edit the main Jenkins config.xml file.

Replace:

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

With:

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Restart the Jenkins service, you should be admin.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I went went solution 2.